# .htaccess · Use rewritecond to work with includes?

Tags: php, .htaccess, templates, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is have multiple directories (created not physically) that granting them access to an file_template.php

For example if you access */soccer/* or for example to */tennis/* or for example to */basket/* ..... redirected internally or make an include of template_sport.php

I have implemented this. Htaccess does not work

```
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} /soccer/(. *)
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} /basket/(. *)
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI} /tennis/(. *)
RewriteRule (.*) /template_sport.php?sport=$1
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RewriteCond`s for that:

```
RewriteRule ^(soccer|basket|tennis)(/.*)?$ /template_sport.php?sport=$1
```

Note that, as written, this `RewriteRule` throws away anything in the URL after the initial `/sport/`.  However, the regexp does capture it in `$2`, so you can include it in the rewritten URL if you want.